Can ReentrantLock.hasQueuedThreads() be used reliably at all?
Java's documentation for ReentrantLock.hasQueuedThreads() says this:

Note that because cancellations may occur at any time, a true return does not guarantee that any other thread will ever acquire this lock. This method is designed primarily for use in monitoring of the system state.

I get that it is unsafe to rely on the return value of hasQueuedThreads() if other threads could be calling e.g. lockInterruptibly() or tryLock(timeout), but does this warning apply even if I can guarantee that all threads will only ever call lock()?

The problem which lead me to this question is this: I have multiple threads that may have to interact with an external device. This device needs to be powered on before it can be accessed, but it should be put to sleep whenever possible to preserve battery. So the behaviour I would like the threads to have is this:

Whenever a thread wants to access the device, it acquires a lock (using lock()).
Once the lock is acquired, the thread powers on the device if needed and then does what it has to do.
Once the thread is done, it checks whether any other thread is waiting for the lock. If so, it leaves the device powered on, if not it powers down the device.

Of course, for this to work reliably I need lock.hasQueuedThreads() to be a reliable indicator of whether another thread will be taking over the responsibility of powering down the device.
Another design I had considered is that all threads would submit their workloads to a single driver thread, but that looks like the entry gate to callback hell, so I'd rather not go there 

Having a worker thread that serializes access to the device might actually be a good idea. You could throw in some event-driven communication, i.e. use messages to pass workloads and results. The other threads might then intermittently work with the results while the device thread processes other workloads. If the work queue is empty you could power down the device or add some wait time for any workload that might come in with a little delay (depends on how fast the device is powered up again and how much power would be used).

Right, I did not think about event-driven communication and agree that with it, the device thread design becomes much more dev-friendly.

You asked, "does this warning apply even if I can guarantee that all threads will only ever call lock()?"  I think the answer to that part of your question is explicit in the Javadoc:

public final boolean hasQueuedThreads()

Queries whether any threads are waiting to acquire this lock...

And

public void lock()

...If the lock is held by another thread then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired...

If we can agree that "lies dormant until the lock has been acquired" and "waits to acquire the lock" both mean the same thing, then clearly, the existence of a thread waiting in an m.lock() call would cause m.hasQueuedThreads() to return true.


the behaviour I would like the threads to have is this:
...Once the thread is done, it checks whether any other thread is waiting for the lock...for this to work reliably I need lock.hasQueuedThreads() to be a reliable indicator...

If thread A owns lock m when it calls m.hasQueuedThreads(), and if the hasQueuedThreads() call returns true because thread B is waiting in an m.lock() call, then where's the problem? Thread B is in the queue. It cannot possibly leave the queue before it acquires the lock. It cannot possibly acquire the lock before thread A releases it.
If thread B were waiting in a lockInterruptibly call or a tryLock call, then yeah. The answer could change, but the way you asked, "... even if I can guarantee that all threads will only ever call lock()?" suggests that you aren't going to call those other functions.
